# Authentication failure on Jenkins, when running build

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh

I was following this guide [link](https://medium.com/sai-ops/deploy-jenkins-agents-using-ec2-spot-instances-44b02f68cd) to use an ec2-fleet plugin to create spot instances from the auto-scaling group. I can ssh into the newly created instance using ssh by going to the main Jenkins server, but when I run a build, I get this error.

```
SSHLauncher{host='10.0.8.128', port=22, credentialsId='ec2-user', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.NonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[02/24/24 14:48:14] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 10.0.8.128:22.
Connection refused
SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection refused", retrying in 15 seconds. There are 10 more retries left.
[02/24/24 14:48:44] [SSH] WARNING: SSH Host Keys are not being verified. Man-in-the-middle attacks may be possible against this connection.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for ec2-user (credentialId:ec2-user/method:publickey)
[02/24/24 14:48:44] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[02/24/24 14:48:44] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[02/24/24 14:48:44] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

- The initial retry step seems to be because the instance is starting) to use an ec2-fleet plugin to create spot instances from the auto-scaling group. I can ssh into the newly created instance using ssh by going to the main Jenkins server, but when I run a build, I get this error.
- the ec2 fleet plugin is able to load the agents
- I tried adding the private key(.pem) to id_rsa and generate a public key from that, after which I could ssh into the remote machine which when doing jenkins build couldn't
- I added the SSH with username and private key, manually pasting the content of the private key
- tried just normal username with password